# Missing Number error when creating newpage

Tags: titles

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{words}
\author{words}
\date{words}

\begin{document}

    \pagenumbering{Gobble}
    \maketitle

    {\centering
    \thanks{words}\par
    }
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
\end{document}
```

I'm completely new to Latex and this site as well so i'm sorry if i've formatted incorrectly.

Now I'm trying to create an entirely seperate title page, without including '\newpage' the document works fine with the title and descriptions at the top of the page, however as soon as i add \newpage it comes up with the error

!Missing number, treated as zero.

<*to be read again*>

\hfil

l.17\newpage

?

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is mostly the capital G in Gobble, but I would do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{words}
\author{words\thanks{zzz}}
\date{words}

\begin{document}


    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah thanks a lot, what does \thispagestyle{empty} do?

Comment: @LG it does what i assumed you were trying to do with Gobble, it removes the page head and foot from the title page  (probably not really needed: \maketitle does `\thispagestyle{plain}` anyway (which removes the head,

Comment: ahh that makes sense, and yeah gobble was used to remove the page number! Thanks a lot i'll get this going